# Php condition doesn't work for html

Tags: php, html, if-statement

I currently want to display a link only on a certain page. The architecture on the website itself is over the `index.php?menu=<pagename>`. So I thought I could simply use:

```
<?php 
      echo $_GET["menu"];
      if($_GET["menu"] = "mMenu-Point") : 
?>
         <a href="www.google.ch">Test</a>
<?php 
      endif; 
?>
```

to execute the htm-code. However it seems like the code will be executed regardless what the value of the "menu" is. I tested this through the echo which strangely gets me the correct values.

I hope you can explain me why this doesn't work.

Thank you very much for your time and efforts!

Comment: `=` is assignment. `==` is condition check

Comment: you are assigning a value instead of checking for it in your if condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
if($_GET["menu"] == "mMenu-Point") :
```

At the moment you are setting (=) `$_GET["menu"]` not comparing it (==)

Comment: *Sigh* I'm so stupid, after trying all other variants I forgot the one that works. Thank you very much for the fast help!

Comment: It's not stupid, it is something we have all done at some time, the other one that catches people out is if they accidentally put a ; after the if

Answer (score 3):

The assignment operator (=) is used to assign a value to a variable, element of an array, or property of an object

The equality operator (==) is used to compare two values or expressions. It is used to compare numbers, strings, Boolean values, variables, objects, arrays, or functions.

You're using the assignment operator `=` here. You need

```
if($_GET["menu"] == "mMenu-Point") :
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Your using the assignment operator (which is one equals) You need to use the comparison operator (`==`) or even (`===` For an exact match)

http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

So you need to be using:

```
if ($_GET["menu"]) == "mMenu-Point") :
```

For comparing to strings, I would recommend using the exact match operator `===`

Answer (score 0):

Double "=" :

```
if($_GET["menu"] == "mMenu-Point")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if($_GET["menu"] == "mMenu-Point") :
```

tow "=" pls